# Odds ratio of Non-Parametric models

Tags: nonparametric, likelihood-ratio

I have two groups and 2 vectors of real numbers $\in [0,1]$ of length $n$ each, $\bar v_1, \bar v_2$.

I would like to calculate odds ratio of 3 models: $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2, H_1: \mu_1 > \mu_2, H_2: \mu_1 < \mu_2$. I.e., if all values in $\bar v_1$ are greater than all values in $\bar v_2$, the hypothesis $H_1$ is highly probable while $H_2$ is not.

I know that I can calculate p-values for one-sided and two-sided Mann-Whitney U tests. Can I somehow extract something similar to odds ratio from the values of one-sided/two-sided Mann Whitney test statistic? Purely empirical and wrong approach: look at the p-values ratios, but I know that it is terribly wrong.

Comment: If you have no assumptions, how are going to compute a likelihood in the first place?

Comment: @whuber this is actually the question. I can look at the differences of vectors and calculate the number of positive and negative differences and use Binomial distribution with $p=0.5$, like in a sign test. The problem is that my observations are not paired...

Comment: If you don't have an explicit model, you don't have a likelihood.  This question is therefore a non-starter: you're not going to get useful answers.  Might I suggest editing it to ask about what you would really like to know about your situation?

Comment: @whuber I am afraid that I will be able to describe it only in a "childish" way, but I will edit it.